# SQL for each ID get only newest field

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have a table of transactions with columns: `ID` and `DATE (integer) [ddmmyyyy]`

One `ID` can have more than one transaction. This means `ID` are repeated in the table.

I need to write a query that returns for each `ID` the transaction with the highest date.

Executing : `Select * from transacciones`

Output actual

| ID | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01012022 |
| 2 | 02012022 |
| 3 | 02012022 |
| 1 | 03012022 |
| 3 | 03012022 |

Output deseado:

| ID | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 03012022 |
| 2 | 02012022 |
| 3 | 03012022 |

Comment: You have dates as integers??? That is a very, very bad idea. And how do you do to get the leading 0 in an integer??

Comment: You tagged both mysql and oracle. Please clarify which version you are using: `select version from v$instance;` for Oracle database or `select version();` for MySQL.

Comment: There is no such thing as a date stored as an integer, it is wishful thinking it is a date but **not** restricted to a date. Both 02282022 and 28022022 could represent *Feb 28, 2022*, but as an integer very different. The only valid data type for a date value is `DATE`. You convert some format on insert (update) and from then on it is guaranteed to properly contain a date. (In Oracle you do have to deal with the Time portion as all `DATE` data types  contain time.)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID, MAX(DATE) FROM transacciones  GROUP BY ID;
```

Would work in theory, however as nacho commented, you're going to inevitable have issues with your data trying to store dates as integers (or even strings). They should be stored as DATE or TIMESTAMP.